# I am trying to build contact form using React and Express and it isn't working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nodemailer

I have a form that was built on React. Path to this file is *react_project/src/components/ContactForm/index.js*

```
const FormSection = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("Submit");
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setStatus("Sending...");
    const { name, email,phone, text } = e.target.elements;
    let details = {
      name: name.value,
      email: email.value,
      message: phone.value,
      text: text.value,
    };
    let response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/contact", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(details),
    });
    setStatus("Submit");
    let result = await response.json();
    alert(result.status);
  };
    return (
       <Container id="contacts">
           <FormWrap>
               <FormContent>
                   <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                       <FormH1>Залиште контакти</FormH1>
                       <FormH2>І ми з вами неодмінно зв’яжемося</FormH2>
                       <FormLabel htmlFor='for'></FormLabel>
                       <FormInput type='name' placeholder="Ваше ім'я" id='name' required />
                       <FormInput type='email' placeholder="E-mail" id='email' required />
                       <FormInput type='phone' placeholder="Номер телефону" id='phone' required />
                       <FormInput type='text' placeholder="Повідомлення" id='text' />
                       <FormButton type='submit'>{status}</FormButton>
                   </Form>
               </FormContent>
           </FormWrap>
       </Container>
    )
}

export default FormSection;
```

And I have file with my backend. Path is *react_project/src/server.js*

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const cors = require("cors");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/", router);
app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server Running"));

const contactEmail = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: "my_email@gmail.com",
    pass: "my_password",
  },
});

contactEmail.verify((error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Ready to Send");
  }
});

router.post("/contact", (req, res) => {
  const name = req.body.name;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const phone = req.body.phone;
  const text = req.body.text; 
  const mail = {
    sender: `<${email}>`,
    to: "slavagodlevsky@gmail.com",
    subject: "Contact Form Message",
    html: `<p>Name: ${name}</p><p>Email: ${email}</p><p>Phone: ${phone}</p><p>Message: ${text}</p>`,
  };
  contactEmail.sendMail(mail, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      res.json({ status: "ERROR" });
    } else {
      res.json({ status: "Message Sent" });
    }
  });
});
```

I already did less security of my google account, but I don't receive any emails. I actually don't know where is the issue. Then I press the button to submit, status changes to "Sending..." and nothing happens. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: You're fetching localhost:5000 and your server is running on localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps to debug:

- Check in your dev tools in your network tab in your browser
- Serverside, add the [morgan](https://bundlephobia.com/package/morgan@1.10.0) package and use it (`app.use(morgan())`) to log requests
- Serverside, add some `console.log` in your route.

Personnally, I think the problem may be due to the lack of [body parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html):

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

That way `req.body` will be correctly set.